# How to model a profile picture type of field in user entity in domain driven design?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I am developing an application with DDD approach where user is one of the entities.
User entity has the following fields / properties :

```
public class User : BaseEntity 
{
   public FirstName FirstName {get; set;}
   public LastName LastName {get; set;}
   public EmailAddress EmailAddress {get; set;}
   public Password Password {get; set;}
   public Role Role {get; set;}
   public ??? ProfilePicture {get; set;}
}
```

FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, etc are all value objects.

There is a registration api using which the profile picture is being uploaded as **IFormFile** in a multi-part form request.

**Q1. What is the proper data type for ProfilePicture?**

**Q2. Should I create a value object representing the profile picture image? If yes, please suggest how to convert IFormFile to that value object?**

**If there is a standard way to approach such a case please let me know**

Comment: What _domain logic_ is going to be influenced by the information in the ProfilePicture?

Comment: There are use cases like remove profile picture, update profile picture, etc...so i need to handle them in ddd style i.e. business logic must be in domain layer hence i will require a way to represent File objects.
Furthermore, there are features in the application for managing documents of the user like resume, id proof, etc so even in those cases i will require the representation of File object in domain layer

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion
1- create Picture Class

```
public class Picture {
 //the type of image like (JPG,PING)
 public string Type {get; set;}
 //the actual data for the image
 public byte[] ImageData {get; set;}
}
```

2- read data from IFormFile where file is IFormFile

```
        //Create new object of picture
        Picture p = new Picture();

        //Set the Type of image file
        p.Type = file.ContentType;

        //Set the Image to an empty byte[] with the same length of file
        p.ImageData = new byte[file.Length];

        //Read the file through the stream
        using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            stream.Read(p.ImageData);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is pretty much what i had in mind.
But consider this use case, when i want to update user profile, i will be fetching the details from the database, at that time i will get profile picture as an URI so how can i convert URI to an object of Picture class? Please let me know if you have an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For how to convert a file to byte array:

```
public class Picture
{
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
Picture p = new Picture();
var filePath = @"wwwroot\image\image1.PNG";
var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

file.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        
p.ImageData = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add , edit , delete Picture using URL right ?

1- Create Image Controller

```
[Route("image")]
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    [Route("image/get/{UserID}")]
    public FileContentResult Index(int UserID)
    {
        //write your way get the user from database
        var user = _repositroy.Users(UserID);

        //Check if User is exist
        if (user != null)
        {
            //Check if has a profile image
            if (user.ProfilePicture.ImageData != null)
            {
                //Return File type
                return File(user.ProfilePicture.ImageData, user.ProfilePicture.Type);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    [Route("image/edit/{UserID}")]
    public FileContentResult Edit(int UserID , IFormFile NewImage)
    {
        //write your way get the user from database
        var user = _repositroy.Users(UserID);

        //Create new object of picture
        Picture picture = new Picture();

        //Set the Type of image file
        picture.Type = NewImage.ContentType;

        //Set the Image to an empty byte[] with the same length of file
        picture.ImageData = new byte[NewImage.Length];

        //Read the file through the stream
        using (var stream = NewImage.OpenReadStream())
        {
            stream.Read(picture.ImageData);
        }

        //Updae the user with the new image
        user.ProfilePicture = picture;

        //if you like to return the new image
        return File(picture.ImageData, picture.Type);
    }
    
    [Route("image/delete/{UserID}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(int UserID)
    {
        //write your way get the user from database
        var user = _repositroy.Users(UserID);

        //Delete the image 
        user.ProfilePicture = null; //or empty it

        //return what you like 
    }
}
```

3- the api is
https://localhost:5500/image/get/1234 for get image
https://localhost:5500/image/edit/1234 for edit image
https://localhost:5500/image/delete/1234 for delete image